# Vue2: How to specify the vue-router root component?

Tags: mvvm, ecmascript-6, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I was just upgraded to Vue2.0, and not so familiar with it.

One change makes trouble for me, that the vue-router initialization [[docs]](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration-vue-router.html#Router-Initialization) is changed:

In my case, the initialization code is changed as below:

#### Old

```
import RootApp from './components/RootApp.vue';

router.start(RootApp, '#app')
```

#### New

```
import RootApp from './components/RootApp.vue';

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router: router,
  render: h => h(RootApp)
})
```

Soon I found that specifying the `RootApp` in such a manner of new case make the root app code ambiguous for me.

That in old case, the `$root` element of each sub-route element yields the `RootApp` instance, while in new case, it yields another component which contains the `RootApp` instance as its only child.

So, it makes trouble, is there any way to create the `RootApp` just acts the root node in Vue2?

Or I guess, is there any way to create an Vue instance like the below (but failed when tried):

```
# Failed code to tell what I want

import RootApp from './component/RootApp.vue';
new RootApp({
    el: '#app',
    router: router,
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a long time to test, I found the last attempt is almost there, see another question:

[Vue.js 2: How to initialize(construct) a Vue component from a .vue file?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40905292/2544762)

The following code worked perfectly!

```
import RootApp from './component/RootApp.vue';
const RootAppConstructor = Vue.extend(RootApp);
new RootAppConstructor({
    el: '#app',
    router: router,
});
```

Comment: That's a nice way around refactoring. +1 - would also maintain your <style> tags which is really good

Comment: @GuyC what do you mean by maintain the <style> tag? Any question posted or something else?

Comment: no question - just if you'd used my answer you would of had to have worked with the CSS in a different manner, however with the method above you have a `<style>` tag within your `.vue` file which will allow you to set base styles for the whole app. Basically I like this idea - nice one!

Answer (score 1):

You could refactor your `RootApp` so that it's methods / data etc... all reside within this new root Vue instance.

This will mean also copying across `RootApp`'s template to your main `index.html` (or whatever you use) file. When done though everything should function as before, albeit not from a single `.vue` file.

Comment: Don't understand. I just want the redundant root component to be collapsed.

Comment: Sorry that's what I was saying, that you could refactor your current app by moving your methods, data etc.. into that new root instance - thus making it not redundant. As far as I'm aware you can't render a child component and then ask Vue to consider it the $root, and nor can you use a .vue file as the root of your app