# Vue.js 2: How to initialize(construct) a Vue component from a .vue file?

Tags: mvvm, ecmascript-6, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to create a Component instance:

#### `App.vue`

```
import MyComponent from './components/MyCompnent.vue';
export default {
    mounted() {
        // The following line fails.
        const vm = new MyComponent();
        vm.$mount('#some-place');
    }
}
```

and the `new` line reports an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: MyComponent.default is not a constructor

So how if I want to create the component?

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: @trusktr it would have an extra redundant tag emebed inside the html tags which I don't want.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Finally, I found the solution myself, very simple:

The `Component` imported itself is not a constructor, but we can easily make a constructor:

```
import MyComponent from './components/MyCompnent.vue';
const MyComponentConstructor = Vue.extend(MyComponent);
```

So the final solution is:

```
import MyComponent from './components/MyCompnent.vue';
export default {
    mounted() {
        const MyComponentConstructor = Vue.extend(MyComponent);
        const vm = new MyComponentConstructor();
        vm.$mount('#some-place');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Following is the way to register a component inside other component:

```
export default {
  el: '#some-place'
  components: {
      'my-component'
  }
}
```

Documentation: [link](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Local-Registration)

### Edited: How to create vm instance

If you want to initialise the vm instance, you can do it using [Vue.extend](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-extend). What is does is:

> Create a “subclass” of the base Vue constructor. The argument should be an object containing component options.

and one point to note here is:

> The special case to note here is the data option - it must be a function when used with Vue.extend().

You need to make changes similar to following in your code:

```
import MyComponent from './components/MyCompnent.vue';
const vmClass = Vue.extend(MyComponent)
const vm = new MyComponent();
vm.$mount('#some-place');
```

Comment: I just want to initialize a vm instance, just like `new Vue()` returns.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

**Script :**

```
import MyComponent from './components/MyCompnent.vue';

export default {
    name : 'comp',
    components :{
      MyComponent
    }  
  }
```

**Html** 
You can call your component in html like this

```
<template>
<mycomponent></mycomponent>
</template>
```

Comment: I just want to initialize a vm instance, just like `new Vue()` returns.

Comment: I believe that the component in html would be `<my-component></my-component>` because it is camel-cased.