# returning vuejs component from method

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

I am pretty new to vue.js, so I'm not even sure if what I'm trying to do is possible. I am working on developing a Matrix component that I could then use in other applications. My problem is that I would like for the getIdentity() method to return a new Matrix component with an array passed into it

```
export default {
  name: 'Matrix',
  props: {
    initRows: Number,
    initColumns: Number,
    initValues: Array
  },
  data () {
    return {
      editable: true,
      contents: [],
      rows: 1,
      columns: 1
    }
  },
  created () {
    ...
  },
  methods: {
    addColumn () {...},
    removeColumn (column) {...},
    addRow () {...},
    removeRow (row) {...},
    getRREF () {...},
    getInverse () {...},
    getIdentity () {
      if (this.rows === this.columns) {
        let tempMtx = [];
        for (let row = 0; row < this.rows; row++) {
          tempMtx[row] = [];
          for (let col = 0; col < this.columns; col++) {
            tempMtx[row][col] = row === col ? 1 : 0;
          }
        }
        return new Matrix({propsData: {initValues: tempMtx}}); // This is the part I can't figure out
      } else {
        throw new Error('Rows and Columns must be equal to get the identity matrix');
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you want to use a component returned from that method?

Comment: Well I would want it to be a Matrix object/component that I could then either display to the user or perform operations such as using the getInverse() method or like concatenating two Matrix objects together. I know that in Java it is possible to call a class's constructor from within a method in the class, and I was hoping to get similar behavior here. I tries to do "let MatrixClass = vue.extends(this)", which was returning a vue component but did not have any of the data that should have been in it.

Comment: I think you might be better served having a Matrix object/class and a component that renders it (accepts a Matrix as a prop). But it sounds like you got yourself working so good job!

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring it out with a bit of help from [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40905292/vue-js-2-how-to-initializeconstruct-a-vue-component-from-a-vue-file). Except that instead of importing it from another file, I just defined `let MatrixConstructor = vue.extend(this.a);`

Comment: The constructor definition also needs to be after the export statement